# How to get selected DIV's HTML along with specified value of controls inside DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net

I have created a div. And in this div I have added textbox on HTML Button click. There is another button called "SHOW". On click of this button I want to display whole the content of this div. Using `document.getElementByID('#div').innerHTML`, I am able to get HTML text inside of this div.

My issue is when I type something into this dynamically created textbox and then when I click show button, it won't show entered text in textbox. My question is, how can I get HTML of whole div with the values entered in the textboxes?
Here is my code snipet:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"   CodeBehind="WebForm9.aspx.cs" Inherits="E_FormDemo.WebForm9" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#Button1').click(function () {
            AddText();
        });

        function AddText() {
            var value;
            value = '<input class="dvHover" id="Text" type="text">';
            $(value).appendTo('#div1');
        };

        $('#Button2').click(function () {
            getText();
        });

        function getText() {
            var s;
            s = document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML;
            alert(s);
        };

    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="show" /></form>
<div id="div1">

</div>
</body>
```

Quick responses are highly appreciable.
Thanks

Comment: Give us some code please! JsFiddle?

Comment: `getElementByID('#div')` is invalid. First of all it is mis-capitalized, and second you don't want the `#` unless you are using jQuery or querySelector.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are looking to achieve. You have a DIV element with input fields in it and you want to get the HTML contents of that DIV as well as values of the INPUT fields in that same DIV? Sounds like you're doing something wrong. Consider adding some code and a better explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: provide your code snippet

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I will show you my code and explain it briefly.

Comment: Sorry for inconvience. When on button click event I have added a textbox to div and on show button click event I want whole div's HTML text to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assign new id to each textbox and on change of the  text box's content update the value using:

var v = $(this).val();

$(this).attr('value', v);

Here is the updated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    var i = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {


        $('#Button1').click(function () 
        {
            AddText();
        });

        function AddText() 
        {
            var value;
            value = '<input class="dvHover" id="Text' + i++ + '" type="text" value="">';
            $(value).appendTo('#div1');
        };

        $('#Button2').click(function() 
        {
            getText();
        });

        function getText() {
            var s;
            s = document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML;
            alert(s);
        };
    });

    $(document).on('change', '.dvHover', function () 
    {
        var v = $(this).val();
        $(this).attr('value', v);
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="show" /></form>
<div id="div1">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, @Mojo_Manga , Thanks for your reply. It works for me. Thank you once again.